# Cloud Run Fails on Step-2 Deploy with Permissions Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am having a heck of a time getting Cloud Run to work correctly. I am creating a new service from the GCP console with a Cloud Build trigger to my Github repo. Under the security tab, I am setting the service account to one of my service accounts which has the following permissions:

1. Cloud Build Service Account
2. Cloud Run Admin
3. Cloud Run Service Agent
4. Cloud Scheduler Service Agent
5. Service Account User

When I create the service, it always ends with the following error:

> Step #2 - "Deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.services.get' denied on resource 'namespaces/project/services/cloud_run_service_name' (or resource may not exist).

I can't figure out why I am getting this error. The service account has all the permissions listed in the [Cloud Run documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#permissions_required_to_deploy). Any ideas?

Comment: Edit your question. Your question includes the error message but not the context and commands that you are executing. 1) Show the commands that you are using to build the image and deploy to Cloud Run. 2) Which identity are you using? 3) Which roles does that identity possess (show the command and output listing the IAM roles). 4) The roles listed are correct. That means you are using a different identity that does not have those roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I was assuming that I should setup everything from Cloud Run, including my Cloud Build trigger since the Cloud Run interface offers that capability. Setting up the Cloud Build Trigger from Cloud Run doesn't take into account the service account that should be controlling the trigger.

The solution was to do everything from Cloud Build where I am able to specify the service account for the trigger and use a cloudbuild.yaml to control deploying to a Cloud Run service.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Cloud Build to deploy the Cloud Run service, the Cloud Build service account must have the appropriate permissions over Cloud Run. You are only specifying that you are adding the permission to "one of my service accounts", but it must be the one used by Cloud Build. The error that you get indicates that the Cloud Build service account does not have the right permissions so you must have set them for the wrong one.

You should add the role Cloud Run Admin (`roles/run.admin`) to the service account used by Cloud Build.

Comment: This may work, but violates the best practices principle of least privilege.

Comment: run.services.get will not allow you to build and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to set the default cloudbuild account up (**number**@cloudbuild.gservicesaccount.com) with the proper permissions:

- Cloud Build Service Account
- Service Account User
- Cloud Run Developer

For your adhoc github service account, my proposal of minimum set of privileges is:

- Container Registry Service Agent
- Cloud Build Service Agent
- Service Account User
- Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object Viewer

Finally, although you can do everything from the Cloud Build service, the same can be done without triggers, that is, using github workflows and cloudbuild.yml files.